# how do I check my code version in git lab?

Tags: git, github

I want to check version of code file uploaded to master/branch in gitlab.
Which should help me finding the right version of the code file when modification happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an errror occurs in a file in production, the most advisable is to review the files that we believe have been the cause of these and look for possible errors individually.

One way to verify the modifications made to a file is to see the modifications of the file, in reference to your commits. In Gitlab:

Going to the file to be reviewed :

[image: Blame]

And there we will see the different modifications by commit :

[image: Blame2]